# Decrypt aes crypted file with php

Tags: php, aes

How can I decrypt aes file with php which is encrypted with c#.

```
private static void AES_Encrypt(string filePath, string passKey)
    {
        string newFilePath = filePath + "." + "aes";
        //byte[] keyPair = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(keyRSA);
        byte[] salt = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
        System.IO.FileStream fsCrypt = new System.IO.FileStream(newFilePath, System.IO.FileMode.Create);
        byte[] passBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(passKey);
        System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged AES = new System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged();
        AES.KeySize = 128;
        AES.BlockSize = 128;
        AES.Padding = System.Security.Cryptography.PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        var key = new System.Security.Cryptography.Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passBytes, salt, 1);
        AES.Key = key.GetBytes(AES.KeySize / 8);
        AES.IV = key.GetBytes(AES.BlockSize / 8);
        AES.Mode = System.Security.Cryptography.CipherMode.CBC;
        fsCrypt.Write(salt, 0, salt.Length);
        System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream cs = new System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream(fsCrypt, AES.CreateEncryptor(), System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        System.IO.FileStream fsIn = new System.IO.FileStream(filePath, System.IO.FileMode.Open);
        fsIn.CopyTo(cs);
        fsIn.Flush();
        fsIn.Close();
        cs.Flush();
        cs.Close();
        fsCrypt.Close();
    }
```

I can decrypt it with c# but when I am trying to decrypt it with php I get some errors.

```
<?php
```

require **DIR** . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use phpseclib\Crypt\AES;

$cipher = new AES('cbc');

$cipher->setKey(str_repeat('a', 16));

$cipher->setIV(str_repeat('b', 16));

$file = file_get_contents("file.aes");

echo $cipher->decrypt($file);

$encryptedData = openssl_decrypt($file, 'AES_128_CBC', "123123", 0);

---

When I am using $cipher->decrypt($file); it does not work but no error shows up.

When I am using $encryptedData = openssl_decrypt($file, 'AES_128_CBC', "123123", 0);

I get this error .

Warning: openssl_decrypt(): Unknown cipher algorithm in C:\OpenServer\domains\panel2\aes.php on line 14

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: there is no error

Comment: The PHP code is missing the key derivation (`Rfc2898DeriveBytes` corresponds to PBKDF2).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you provide example decrypt function in php for my c# code?